# Scroll up parent window with iframe

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, window

I have a web page inside which I've included an external iframe in the middle of it (below the fold). In this iframe, there is an input text, with the blinking cursor (i.e. the focus has been set to that particular input text). So when the page loads, it scrolls down directly to the iframe and the input text.

But I don't want my page to scroll down, or I want to scroll back up after it has been completely loaded/ready.

Do you know any way to scroll up my parent window to the top AFTER it has focused on the iframe input text? I don't have any access to the iframe source code...

I've been given this piece of code:
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(.my-wrapper input).focus();
    });

where my-wrapper is a search form at the top of my page, but it doesn't do the trick...

Please if you could give me a solution with jQuery and with direct DOM instructions, that would be awesome (I'm wondering if its not a problem of my jQuery script being asynchronously loaded AFTER the document ready function).

Thanks a million!!
Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input text on your iframe is grabbing focus, so you may want to try this onload (possibly within a settimeout):

```
$('html,body').scrollTop()
```

Comment: @NicolasDdn, settimeout lets you delay the execution of a function/code. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp